# How to select rows on infinite row model in ag-grid in angular 4?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have used a custom headerComponent to show a checkbox in the header cell as a select all option in ag-grid with infinite scroll row model. On click of the checkbox i need to be able to select/deselect all rows in the table in the current block of rows. Also on scroll to the end of the table a server call is made to get the next set of rows. The new data loaded should also be selected by default.

I know that the ag-grid does not support the header selection for select all in the infinite row model. How can i do this programmatically? How can i get all the selected rows too.

This is my current code:

Header component :

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {IHeaderParams} from "ag-grid/main";
import {IHeaderAngularComp} from "ag-grid-angular";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customheader',
  templateUrl: './customheader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customheader.component.css']
})
export class CustomheaderComponent implements IHeaderAngularComp{
  private params : any;

  agInit(params:any): void {
    console.log(params);
    this.params = params;
  }

  toggleSelectAll(){

  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

Header component template :

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="params.displayName == ''" ><input type="checkbox" class="selectAllCheckBox" (click)="toggleSelectAll()"> </div>
  <div>{{params.displayName}}</div>
</div>
```

Table component :

```
constructor(public appServices:AppServices) {
    this.rowData = this.assayDataList;
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        //headerCheckboxSelection: true,
        //headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
        checkboxSelection: true,
        width: 40,
        headerComponentParams: CustomheaderComponent
      },
      {
        headerName: "Date/Time",
        field: "createdDate",
        width: 230
      },
      {headerName: 'Assay Name', field: 'assayName', width: 240},
      {headerName: 'Samples', field: 'sampleCount', width: 100}

    ];

    this.gridOptions = {
      rowSelection: 'multiple',
      cacheBlockSize: 30,
      //maxBlocksInCache: 2,
      enableServerSideFilter: false,
      enableServerSideSorting: false,
      rowModelType: 'infinite',
      paginationAutoPageSize: true,
      suppressRowClickSelection: true
      //suppressCellSelection: true
    };

    this.frameworkComponents = { agColumnHeader: CustomheaderComponent };

  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Had this issue as well, there's a callback function for each row node `forEachNode((node, index))`, you can loop through an set each selection on your select-all event.

```
 gridApi.forEachNode((row, index) => {
            gridApi.getRowNode(row.id).selectThisNode(true);
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution to make the new chunk of the data selected. Not sure how would you be able to propagate the flag for `selectAll` from `CustomheaderComponent` to your grid component, so just answering assuming you already have access to `selectAll` flag inside the component.

When you get the new chunk of data, after you call `successCallback`, do the selection logic.

```
params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, this.count);
this.manageRecordsWithSelectAllFlag(rowsThisPage);
```

Get the id of the new records, grab the `RowNode` and then use `RowNode.selectThisNode` function to select it.

```
private manageRecordsWithSelectAllFlag(rowsThisPage: any[]): void {
  let id;
  if(this.selectedAll) {
    for(let x = 0; x < rowsThisPage.length; x++) {
      id = rowsThisPage[x]['yourIdProperty'];
      this.gridApi.getRowNode(`${id}`).selectThisNode(this.selectedAll);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hey, thank you for this, +1, it helped, just curious if you later found any better way to programmatically select rows while `rowModelType` is `infinite`..

Comment: Hi guys! I'm having some problems implementing this solution! Can you please tell me what is 'yourIdProperty'? I have a grid with a list of objects and I tried to specify 'yourIdProperty' as a property of this row object but it doesn't work. Can you please give me an example? Thank you in advance

Comment: I fix the problem with RowIndex instead of IdProperty: gridInstance.api.getRowNode(rowIndex).selectThisNode(false); Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

**Simple solution**

Select all:

```
gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
  node.setSelected(true);
});
```

Deselect All

```
gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
  node.setSelected(false);
});
```